# How to move points near to road in 3 meter distance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one one table of points and road having both geoms in that table and also the distance of points near to road. But now i want to move thoes points which have distance less then 5 meter to road. Any one help me how can i do this plx help me in making Query for this problem.

[image: its my table]

Comment: Do not include any links! Many people here won't click on unknown links. Instead edit your question and provide your sample data and desired output as `formatted text`. Also tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: DBMS postgres. i m new to postgres sql thats why i dont know.. plz help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ST_LineLocatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) combined to [`ST_LineInterpolatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html)  to get the nearest location on the road

```
UPDATE myTable
SET point_geom = ST_LineInterpolatePoint(road_geom, ST_LineLocatePoint(road_geom, point_geom))
WHERE point_to_road_distance <= 5;
```